Absolute Position of Text Box in Microsoft Word Online
In Microsoft Word, I can insert a text box and give it an absolute position on the page
Desktop Version
But when I open the same file in Microsoft Word online, the positioning is not preserved.
Microsoft Online
Is there something I can do to get a Microsoft Word online document that has text boxes floating at specific positions? There are a lot of other positioning/alignment options but none of them seem to work.
